# Extract continuous numeric characters from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, character, numeric

I am interested in extracting a number that appears after a set of characters (`'AA='`). However, the issue is: (i) I am not aware how long the number is, (ii) I don't know what appears right after the number (could be a blank space or ANY character except 0-9, consider that I do not know what these characters could be but they are definitely not 0-9), (iii) number can be present in exponential form (line 4/5 below)

Given below are few of many inputs that I can have.

```
Line 1: 123 NUBA AA=1.2345 $BB=1234.55
Line 2: 123 NUBA MM AA=1.2345678&BB=1234.55
Line 3: 123 NUBA RRNJH AA=1.2#ALPHA
Line 4: 123 NUBA ABCD AA=1.2E-5 GBRO
Line 5: 123 NUBA ABCD AA=1.245E-7$ MN
...
```

The result should be: `1.2345` `1.2345678` `1.2` `1.2e-5` `1.245e-7` for each respective line above.

PS: I know how to use `.find` and get the starting location of `AA=` but that is not very helpful for the above conditions. Also, **I understand one way could be to loop through each character after after `AA=` and break if a blank space or anything except [`0-9`,`.`, `E`, `-`]  is seen, but that is clumsy and takes unnecessary space** in my code. I am looking for a more neat way of doing this.

Comment: The neat way is to use a regular expression, that's what they were invented for.  Start with the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks, can you please share a simple relevant example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single pattern with a capture group. Use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) for example to get the value of the capture group only.

```
\bAA=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)
```

*Explanation*

- `\bAA=` A word boundary, then match `AA=`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Match an optional decimal part
  - `(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` Match an optional exponential part
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sAIpWW/1)

```
import re
 
regex = r"\bAA=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)"
 
s = ("Line 1: 123 NUBA AA=1.2345 $BB=1234.55\n"
    "Line 2: 123 NUBA MM AA=1.2345678&BB=1234.55\n"
    "Line 3: 123 NUBA RRNJH AA=1.2#ALPHA\n"
    "Line 4: 123 NUBA ABCD AA=1.2E-5 GBRO\n"
    "Line 5: 123 NUBA ABCD AA=1.245E-7$ MN")
 
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['1.2345', '1.2345678', '1.2', '1.2E-5', '1.245E-7']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/qgzo1K)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! I am stuck at some other places which I forgot to include in my question before. Please see my updated question. How Line 4 and 5 can be handled as well please?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. That explanation is very exhaustive and helpful for someone who has never used regex before. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the output you want

```
import re

string1 = '123 NUBA AA=1.2345 $BB=1234.55'
string2 = '123 NUBA MM AA=1.2345678&BB=1234.55'
string3 = '123 NUBA RRNJH AA=1.2#ALPHA'

re.findall(r'\d+\.*\d*', string1[string1.find("AA="):])[0]
re.findall(r'\d+\.*\d*', string2[string2.find("AA="):])[0]
re.findall(r'\d+\.*\d*', string3[string3.find("AA="):])[0]
```

Output

```
1.2345
1.2345678
1.2
```

Comment: This works! But I am stuck at some other places which I forgot to include in my question before. Please see my updated question. How Line4 and 5 can be handled?